# Is there a way to use the Annyang speech recognition API to implement text to speech on the React framework?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a web application similar to Google ok search engine.

I am using using a speech recognition API in my React web application.

I have successfully implemented speech to text. Now I want to implement text to speech in my React web application using the speech recognition API, but I could not find any in their documentation.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Comment: I reformatted your text a bit to make it more readable, but this question is really asking suggestions for a library, which is out of scope for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package [react-speech-recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition)

```
   import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
   import SpeechRecognition from 'react-speech-recognition'

    const propTypes = {
      // Props injected by SpeechRecognition
      transcript: PropTypes.string,
      resetTranscript: PropTypes.func,
      browserSupportsSpeechRecognition: PropTypes.bool
    }

    class Dictaphone extends Component {
      render() {
        const { transcript, resetTranscript, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition } = this.props

        if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
          return null
        }

        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
            <span>{transcript}</span>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    Dictaphone.propTypes = propTypes

    export default SpeechRecognition(Dictaphone)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-speech npm for both text-to-speech and speech-to-text.

This is the GitHub repository: https://github.com/andrewkeig/react-speech